# mostFrequent method bags adt(abstract data types)

Tags: java, bag

I am trying to implement a method named mostFrequent in a bag that finds the most frequent object in a bag For example, if B = {Bob, Joe, Bob, Ned, Bob, Bob}, then the method
returns Bob. Hint: The method is O(n^2).

```
public E MostFrequent (Bag<E> B){ 
// implementation here
}
```

The adt of the bag is the following:

```
package edu.uprm.ece.icom4035.bag;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class StaticBag implements Bag {

    private int currentSize;

    private Object elements[];

    private class BagIterator implements Iterator {

        private int currentPosition;

        public BagIterator(){
            this.currentPosition = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return this.currentPosition < currentSize;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            if (hasNext()){
                return elements[this.currentPosition++];
            }
            else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

    }

    public StaticBag(int maxSize){
        if (maxSize < 1){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Max size must be at least 1.");
        }

        this.currentSize = 0;
        this.elements = new Object[maxSize];
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value cannot be null.");
        }
        else if (this.size() == this.elements.length){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Bag is full.");
        }
        else {
            this.elements[this.currentSize++] = obj;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean erase(Object obj) {
        int target = -1;
        for (int i=0; i < this.size(); ++i){
            if (this.elements[i].equals(obj)){
                target = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (target == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            this.elements[target] = this.elements[this.currentSize-1];
            this.elements[this.currentSize-1] = null;
            this.currentSize--;
            return true;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int eraseAll(Object obj) {
        int copies = 0;
        while(this.erase(obj)){
            copies++;
        }

        return copies;
    }

    @Override
    public int count(Object obj) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < this.size(); ++i){
            if (elements[i].equals(obj)){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        for (int i=0; i < this.size(); ++i){
            this.elements[i] = null;
        }
        this.currentSize = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.size() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return this.currentSize;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMember(Object obj) {
        return this.count(obj) > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new BagIterator();
    }

}
```

the method must be implemented in the most efficient way and if possible using the methods already given in the bag adt

What I've been trying is the following:

```
public E MostFrequent(Bag<E> B){
    for(E e : B){
        int counter = B.count(e)

    }
}
```

but I don't seem to think of a way to return the object with more frequencies inside the loop

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?

Comment: I need an implementation for the mostFrequent method

Comment: We aren't just going to give it to you. What do you think stackoverflow is?

Comment: hey man i'm just looking for a little bit of help here if you don't want to, its fine by me, I've been hours trying to figure out this problem and the less thing I need its your attitude like you own this page and like any other person has never got an answer in this forum

Comment: Read and follow [this](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Your question now seems like you want us to do your work for you. We won't. If that's not what you were asking for, reword your question and show us your attempts and why they didn't work.

Comment: What i am trying to do is something like this for (E e : B) int count = B.count(e)   but I dont know with what compare the value to be able to return the e object